# How to stretch the background image to fill a div

Tags: css, html, background, background-image

I want to set a background image to different divs, but my problems are:

1. The size of image is fixed(60px).
2. Varying  div's size

How can I stretch the background-image to fill the whole background of the div?

```css
#div2{
  background-image:url(http://s7.static.hootsuite.com/3-0-48/images/themes/classic/streams/message-gradient.png);
  height:180px;
  width:200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Check the code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/qdzaw/)

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Add

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

to your css underneath background-image.

You can also specify exact dimensions, i.e.:

```
background-size: 30px 40px;
```

Here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdzaw/7/)

Comment: IE not support this. Wt to do?

Comment: it doesn't work, see bellow for a better answer: background-size:100% 100%;

Comment: Why is it multiplying instead of stretching the image to fit the container: http://jsfiddle.net/qdzaw/424/

Comment: You need to add `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: @KarSho for OLD IEs => strech image to parent: make `<img>` element with these css: `position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:auto;`, this element should be first child of its parent :) Or `height: 100%;` if you want 100% spread - might cause deformation ....

Comment: hendo, your JSFiddle is no longer working (dead links to hootsuite), can you please update it?

Comment: It didn't work for me until I used in-line CSS.  That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: this does not work,  answer below background-size:cover works

Answer (score 89):

You can use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Or just use a big background image with:

```
background: url('../images/teaser.jpg') no-repeat center #eee;
```

Comment: cover doesnt strech, it can cut picture

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with your background img but `background-size: cover; background-position: center` will fill the background of the `div` without stretching the image

Comment: Works great for pictures where stretching would disform the image!

Answer (score 53):

## Modern CSS3 (recommended for the future & probably the best solution)

```
.selector{
   background-size: cover;
   /* stretches background WITHOUT deformation so it would fill the background space,
      it may crop the image if the image's dimensions are in different ratio,
      than the element dimensions. */
}
```

**Max. stretch without crop nor deformation *(may not fill the background)*:** `background-size: contain;`

**Force absolute stretch *(may cause deformation, but no crop)*:** `background-size: 100% 100%;`

## "Old" CSS "always working" way

Absolute positioning image as a first child of the *(relative positioned)* parent and stretching it to the parent size.

**HTML**

```
<div class="selector">
   <img src="path.extension" alt="alt text">
   <!-- some other content -->
</div>
```

#### Equivalent of CSS3 `background-size: cover;` :

To achieve this dynamically, you would have to use the **opposite of contain method alternative** (see below) and if you need to center the cropped image, you would need a JavaScript to do that dynamically - e.g. using jQuery:

```
$('.selector img').each(function(){ 
   $(this).css({ 
      "left": "50%", 
      "margin-left": "-"+( $(this).width()/2 )+"px", 
      "top": "50%", 
      "margin-top": "-"+( $(this).height()/2 )+"px" 
   }); 
});
```

**Practical example:**

[image: css crop like example]

#### Equivalent of CSS3 `background-size: contain;` :

This one can be a bit tricky - the dimension of your background that would overflow the parent will have CSS set to 100% the other one to auto.
**Practical example:**
[image: css stretching background as image]

```
.selector img{
   position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   /* -- OR -- */
   /* width: auto; 
      height: 100%; */
}
```

#### Equivalent of CSS3 `background-size: 100% 100%;` :

```
.selector img{
   position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

*PS: To do the equivalents of cover/contain in the "old" way completely dynamically (so you will not have to care about overflows/ratios) you would have to use javascript to detect the ratios for you and set the dimensions as described...*

Answer (score 24):

For this you can use CSS3 `background-size` property. Write like this:

```css
#div2{
    background-image:url(http://s7.static.hootsuite.com/3-0-48/images/themes/classic/streams/message-gradient.png);
    -moz-background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    height:180px;
    width:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/qdzaw/1/

Comment: IE not support this. Wt to do?

Comment: For IE use **IMG** tag give position absolute with height & width 100%.

Answer (score 22):

You can add:

```css
#div2{
    background-image:url(http://s7.static.hootsuite.com/3-0-48/images/themes/classic/streams/message-gradient.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:180px;
    width:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You can read more about it here: [css3 background-size](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/)

Comment: background-size is a css3 and not supported in all browsers

Answer (score 3):

by using property css:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: background-size is a css3 and not supported in all browsers

Answer (score 2):

```
body{
  margin:0;
  background:url('image.png') no-repeat 50% 50% fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:
background-size: 100% 100%;
To make background image to fit the div size.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the aspect ratio, use `background-size: 100% auto;`

```
div {
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-size: 100% auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
div {
    background-image: url(../img/picture1.jpg);
    height: 30em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```