# How to make bg image width:100% of screen in head module?

Tags: css, joomla3.0

I have joomla CMS with purity III template.
THere is a header module to display head message on my home page.

I add a big bg image 1366 X 534 px. But the image is not display full width.

Please have a look with jconsole on code of 
http://217.23.14.121/~gauthier/docteurimpots/index.php?lang=fr

How to get image in full width of screen?

Does someone can help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stretch the background image to fill a div.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223585/how-to-stretch-the-background-image-to-fill-a-div)

Comment: the image *is* displayed with full width! (just not full height, but that's due to the settings of the container).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't think that it is full screen because on the right there is the border with the vertical bar. You are right it's orrible but this template it's really so.